# declare a function in a .h (library) file as a friend to a class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, friend-function

I’m writing a simple class for list of products and there I need to overload both extraction >> operator and insertion << operator to write into file and read from file

student_projectV1/list.h

```
#ifndef STUDENT_PROJECTV1_LIST
#define STUDENT_PROJECTV1_LIST


#include <fstream>



namespace list {

    class list {

        private:

            string name;
            int price;
            short quantity;


        public:

            ofstream ofs;
            ifstream ifs;


            // file_mutators
            void set_created_file () noexcept(false) ;
            void set_readable_file ();

            // constructors
            list() noexcept ( noexcept ( set_created_file() ) )  ;

            list ( string  , int , short  ) noexcept(false) ;
            list ( class list &) noexcept ( noexcept ( set_created_file() ) ) ;

            // initialization to cover after construction of an obj
            void initialize ( string , int , short ) noexcept(false) ;

            // mutators
            void set_name ( string ) noexcept(false);
            void set_price ( int ) noexcept(false) ;
            void set_quantity ( short ) noexcept(false) ;


            // accessors

            string get_name ( ) const  noexcept;
            int get_price () const noexcept;
            int get_quantity () const noexcept;


            // Enqueries
            bool check_created_file () noexcept;
            bool check_opened_file();

            // destructor
            ~list();



            // friend global functions
            // overloaded operators

            friend ofstream & friend_global_funcs :: operator << ( ofstream & , class list::list &) ;
            friend ifstream &  friend_global_funcs :: operator >> ( ifstream & , class list::list &) ;


    };
}


#endif
```

now I plan to place the definition of these two overloaded functions in another  `friend_global_funcs.h` file inside a namespace

```
friend ofstream & friend_global_funcs :: operator << ( ofstream & , class list::list &) ;
friend ifstream &  friend_global_funcs :: operator >> ( ifstream & , class list::list &) ;
```

friend_global_funcs.h

```
//
// Created by solo-l-ub on 2/27/22.
//

#ifndef STUDENT_PROJECTV1_FRIEND_GLOBAL_FUNCS_H
#define STUDENT_PROJECTV1_FRIEND_GLOBAL_FUNCS_H





namespace friend_global_funcs {

    ofstream & operator<< (ofstream &ofs, class list::list &l)  {

        if (!l.check_created_file())
            throw new file_missing::file_missing(
                    "can not write info to file something wrong with acquiring file in constructor of obj \n");


        ofs << l.name() << "\t" << l.price << "\t" << l.quantity << "\n";

        return ofs;

    }


    ifstream & operator>>(ifstream &ifs, list :: list &l) {

        l.set_readable_file();

        if (!l.check_opened_file())
            throw new file_missing::file_missing(
                    "can't retrieve data cuz file is not associated with obj currently I'm in operated >> overloaded fuc \n");


        ifs >> l.name >> l.price >> l.quantity;

        return ifs;
    }

}

#endif //STUDENT_PROJECTV1_FRIEND_GLOBAL_FUNCS_H
```

now My scenario of the order of including files in  `main.cpp` file  I’ve included first the class `list.h` and then the `friend_global_funcs.h file`

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// using namespaces


// classes
#include "file_missing.h"
#include "empty.h"
#include "list.h"


// libraries
#include "friend_global_funcs.h"

int main() {



    //////////////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

now when I try to compile in terminal using g++

```
g++ main.cpp -o out
```

I get the error that overloaded functions in  `list.h` are not declared even though I’ve used the scope resolution operator to tell compiler to exactly where to look for the function `friend_global_funcs :: operator <<`

g++ terminal error

```
In file included from main.cpp:33:
list.h:64:31: error: ‘friend_global_funcs’ has not been declared
   64 |             friend ofstream & friend_global_funcs :: operator << ( ofstream & , class list::list &) ;
```

now I’ve uploaded my project which is a very very light project just to practice writing and reading to files from inside classes to github
in case you want to take a look at it and guide me the proper sequence to use the friendship of a function which is defined in another .h file in a class

github src
https://github.com/moji2013/student_projectV1.git

Comment: It is unclear where the functions are declared whether in friend_global_funcs or in list namespace. You need at first to decide that yourself.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , tnx for your close attention , just changed the question. could you please take another look at it?

Comment: the implementation should be in list.cpp not another .h file

Comment: @pm100 alright it can work by putting overloaded functions in list.cpp file , but the question still remains on how to declare friendship of a function which is inside a friend_global_func.h file? I mean what if you had a function in a header file , libary file and wanted to declare friendship to that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that in your current `list.h`, you have 2 **friend declarations** that uses the **scope resolution operator** `::` to refer to `operator<<` and `operator>>` inside the namespace `friend_global_funcs`. And at the point of these friend declaration the compiler doesn't know about the namespace `friend_global_funcs`.

So to **solve** this you need to tell the compiler that there is a namespace called `friend_global_funcs` that has the declarations for `operator<<` and `operator>>` as shown below([Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/59yp_rjZx)):

**list.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT_PROJECTV1_LIST
#define STUDENT_PROJECTV1_LIST


#include <fstream>
#include <string>
namespace list {
    class list;
}
namespace friend_global_funcs {

    std::ofstream & operator << ( std::ofstream & , const list::list &) ; //const added here and keyword class removed from second parameter
    std::ifstream & operator >> ( std::ifstream & , list::list &) ;//keyword class removed from second parameter
}

namespace list {

    class list {

        private:

            std::string name;
            int price;
            short quantity;


        public:

            std::ofstream ofs;
            std::ifstream ifs;


            // file_mutators
            void set_created_file () noexcept(false) ;
            void set_readable_file ();

            // constructors
            list() noexcept ( noexcept ( set_created_file() ) )  ;

            list ( std::string  , int , short  ) noexcept(false) ;
            list ( class list &) noexcept ( noexcept ( set_created_file() ) ) ;

            // initialization to cover after construction of an obj
            void initialize ( std::string , int , short ) noexcept(false) ;

            // mutators
            void set_name ( std::string ) noexcept(false);
            void set_price ( int ) noexcept(false) ;
            void set_quantity ( short ) noexcept(false) ;


            // accessors

            std::string get_name ( ) const  noexcept;
            int get_price () const noexcept;
            int get_quantity () const noexcept;


            // Enqueries
            bool check_created_file () const noexcept;//const added here
            bool check_opened_file();

            // destructor
            ~list();



            // friend global functions
            // overloaded operators

            friend std::ofstream & friend_global_funcs :: operator << ( std::ofstream & , const list &) ;//const added here
            friend std::ifstream &  friend_global_funcs :: operator >> ( std::ifstream & , list &) ;


    };
    
}

#endif
```

**list.cpp**

```
#include "list.h"
#include"empty.h"
#include "file_missing.h"
namespace list{
// constructors
list :: list () noexcept ( noexcept ( set_created_file() ) )  {
    // give 'em a valid obj
    // ,and a most common one
    name = "not_set" , price = 1 , quantity = 1;

    // not sure weather to call the
    set_created_file();
    // or simply call this
//    ofs.open("list.txt", ios::app);
}

list :: list ( std::string name , int price , short quantity ) noexcept(false) {

    set_name ( name );
    set_price ( price );
    set_quantity ( quantity );

    set_created_file();
}

list :: list ( class list &r ) noexcept ( noexcept ( set_created_file() ) )  {

    name = r.name;
    price = r.price;
    quantity = r.quantity;

    // how to copy file location then?

//    ofs = r.ofs;
    set_created_file();
}
////


// initialization to cover after construction of an obj
void list :: initialize ( std::string name , int price , short quantity ) {
    set_name ( name );
    set_price ( price );
    set_quantity ( quantity );
    set_created_file();
}
////

// mutators
void list :: set_name ( std::string name ) noexcept(false) {

    if ( name.empty() )
        throw new empty::empty ( "name can not be left out enter something \n");

    (*this).name = name;
}

void list :: set_price ( int price )  noexcept(false) {

    if ( !price )
        throw new empty :: empty ( "price can not be zero \n" );

    (*this).price = price;
}

void list :: set_quantity ( short quantity ) noexcept(false) {

    if ( !quantity )
        throw new empty :: empty ( "quantity can not be zero \n" );

    (*this).quantity = quantity;
}

/////


// file mutators
void list :: set_created_file () noexcept(false) {

    if ( !ofs.is_open() )
        ofs.open("student_list_file.txt", std::ios::app);

    if ( !ofs.is_open() )
        throw new file_missing :: file_missing ( "file couldn't be created or opened \n" );

}

void list :: set_readable_file () {

    if ( !ifs.is_open() )
        ifs.open ( "student_list_file.txt" );

    if ( !ifs.is_open() )
        throw new file_missing :: file_missing ( "file couldn't be opened by set_readable_file function \n" );

}



////


// accessors
std::string list :: get_name () const noexcept {
    return name;
}
int list :: get_price () const  noexcept {
    return price;

}
int list :: get_quantity () const  noexcept {
    return quantity;
}

///

// enqueries
bool list :: check_created_file () const noexcept{

    return ofs.is_open();
}


bool list :: check_opened_file (){

    return ifs.is_open();
}


// destructive
list :: ~list() {
    // release resources
    // close file
    // close connection
    // release heap memory

    ofs.close();
    ifs.close();

}
}
```

**friend_global_funcs.cpp**

```
#include "list.h"
#include "file_missing.h"
#include "empty.h"
namespace friend_global_funcs {

    std::ofstream & operator<< (std::ofstream &ofs, const list::list &l)  { //const added here

        if (!l.check_created_file())
            throw new file_missing::file_missing(
                    "can not write info to file something wrong with acquiring file in constructor of obj \n");


        ofs << l.name << "\t" << l.price << "\t" << l.quantity << "\n"; //changed l.name() to l.name

        return ofs;

    }


    std::ifstream & operator>>(std::ifstream &ifs, list :: list &l) {

        l.set_readable_file();

        if (!l.check_opened_file())
            throw new file_missing::file_missing(
                    "can't retrieve data cuz file is not associated with obj currently I'm in operated >> overloaded fuc \n");


        ifs >> l.name >> l.price >> l.quantity;

        return ifs;
    }

}
```

[Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/59yp_rjZx)

Some of the changes that i made include:

1. Added namespace `friend_global_funcs` inside file `list.h`. This namespace contains the forward declarations for the `operator<<` and `operator>>`.
2. Added a low-level const to the second parameter of overloaded `operator<<` inside files `list.h` and `friend_global_funcs.cpp`.
3. Changed the name of the file `friend_global_funcs.h` to `friend_global.funcs.cpp` since it contains implementation.

PS: It took me around 30 minutes to create a working example out of your given github repo. There may be other logical errors in your program that i haven't checked because the repo is quite big. I was focusing on the problem at hand(which was to overload `operator<<` and `operator>>`).

Comment: I just can't thank you enough.This problem was on my mind ever since. you just totally nailed it .I deeply appreciate the time and effort you put into this.I learned so many valuable things from your answer and live demo . again I can't thank you enough. God bless you and your family. thank you

Comment: Your online Demo helped a lot and I was afraid files might get deleted from onlineDGB so I just coppied files to a repository on github in your name for future references for anyone having the same problem https://github.com/moji2013/student_project_fixed_by_-Anoop-Rana.git

Comment: @moji Good point. I have also observed that the site onlineGDB(like any other site) does sometimes goes down.

Answer (score 1):

list.h includes friend_global_funcs.h and friend_global_funcs.h includes list.h. This cannot work. A cannot be before B while B is also before A. The header guards prevent infinite recursion, but you end up with one header being first, and thus not having the declartions that it depends on.

A correct solution is to follow this order:

- Declare `list::list`
- Declare `friend_global_funcs::operator<<` and `friend_global_funcs::operator>>`
- Define `list::list`
- Define `friend_global_funcs::operator<<` and `friend_global_funcs::operator>>`

---

P.S. If you define a function in a header file, then you should make that function inline so that you don't accidentally violate one definition rule by including the non-inline definition into multiple translation units. You should also think about why you want to define the functions within a header file.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,but I'm not quite following the steps here. where and how should i implement the steps?i mean how to declare ```list::list``` and in which file?

Comment: @moji Go to the file that defines `list::list`. Make sure that the declaration of  `friend_global_funcs::operator<<` and `friend_global_funcs::operator>>` precede the definition of `list::list`. You also must not include the definition of those functions before defining `list::list` because the definitions of those functinos depend on the definition of `list::list`. So remove the conflicting inclusion of the header that defines those functions.

Comment: I'm still struggling on how to put ```list::list``` declaration before jumping to ```friend_global_func.h``` file. I mean what you're saying is correct let the compiler first see the whole definition of ```list::list``` and then ```#include "freind_global_funcs.h"``` but how to achieve it?

Comment: @moji `let the compiler first see the whole definition of list::list and then #include "freind_global_funcs.h" but how to achieve it?` Include `list.h` in `freind_global_funcs.h`. That way `list::list` will be defined before the functions.

Comment: alright now when i let the compiler see a whole definition of list::list, when it reaches ```namespace list { class list { public : friend ofstream & friend_global_funcs :: operator << ( ofstream & , class list::list &) ; }} ```  it says ``` friend_global_funcs has not been declared; ```

Comment: @moji That's why I said, declare the functions before defining the class. Both in the answer and in the first comment.

Comment: i really appreciate your help and apologize for my numerous questions. by declaring functions you mean providing a prototype? what I'm doing now  in main.cpp is ```#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "file_missing.h"
#include "empty.h"
#include "list.h"
#include "friend_global_funcs.h" ``` as you can see I have put definition of ```list::list``` before and in freind_glob_fun.h I have no includes and in ```list::list``` I have only ```#include <fstream> ```. is there a way to upload my project so that it would be easier for you to take a peak?

Comment: @moji `by declaring functions you mean providing a prototype?` Yes. That's what a declaration is.

Comment: sorry but in which file should I provide a prototype? in ```list.h``` or ```main.cpp```? I've tried nearly everywhere but sill can't run a successful build

Comment: @moji The definition of `list::list` depends on the declaration, so that declaration must be before that definition. Best way to achieve that is to put it in the same file. It can be through including another file. But that another may not be main.cpp because you don't include cpp files and it may not be friend_global_funcs.h because that must be after the definition of `list::list`. It can be a completely separate header file. You could call it friend_global_funcs_fwd.hpp for example.

Comment: I uploaded my project to github ( which is a very simple project  to practice writing to files ) and provided a lik in the question description. could you please read it and tell me where to put the declartion to get rid of the ``` error: ‘friend_global_funcs’ has not been declared``` ?  https://github.com/moji2013/student_projectV1.git